# Learning Windows Batch File Scripting

Tags: windows, scripting

What would be the best course for me to take in regards to learning how to script with Windows? I am a beginner and would like an accelerated course or list of great informational steps to take to become an advanced scripter. In all areas of Windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is what you want to learn.  Google, notepad and experimentation.  I'm sure there are great books as well, but find a tutorial or two and you will be off to the races.

Comment: Any good informational sites that can be given. Why do you say PowerShell scripting is what I want to learn?

Comment: On Windows, PowerShell is the name of the scripting system.  It replaces cmd as the shell (although both are supported).  PowerShell is far more powerful and it's very well supported.  I suggest that you invent a problem (i.e. "I want to rename every file in a directory to prepend the file name with the last modified date").  Probably start with TechNet (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point could be  this=>
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx